# Give a function in $L^p$ but not in weak $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I come across this problem;

1. Define the space Weak $L^p$ in the unit ball $B^n_1(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $1 <p <\infty$.
2. Show an example of a function $f(x)$ such that $f \in L^{p,w}(B_1^n(0),dx)$, but not in the classical $L^p(B_1^n(0))$

**My solution**

1. Consider the measure space $(B_1^n(0), \mathcal{B}(B_1^n(0)),dx)$, and let $f$ be a measurable real-valued function on $B_1^n(0)$. Let the distribution function of $f$ is denoted for $t >0$ by $\lambda_f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where

$$\lambda_f(t) =  \left|\{x \in B_1^n(0): |f(x)|>t \} \right|.$$

Then a function $f$ is said to be in the Weak $L^p(B_1^n(0))$ space if $\exists C>0 $ such that $\forall t >0$, then

$$\lambda_f (t) \leq \frac{C^p}{t^p}.$$

I could not find an example. I assume I can not imagine the behavior of the functions in weal Lebesgue space. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For $n=1$ take $f(x)=|x|^{-1/p}$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you explain (or show a reference) briefly why the weal $L^p$ is important?

Comment: [The  Marcinkiewicz theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz_interpolation_theorem) comes into mine mind. There are important operators which are of weak tyle $(1,1)$ and not of strong type $(1,1),$ like for instance [the Hilbert transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Relationship_with_the_Fourier_transform)

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc It is easy to check the function on the $L^p$ space but I find it not easy to check the weak $L^p$ space. Is satisfying the condition $\int_0^\infty t^{p-1} \lambda_f(t) dt < \infty$ equivalent to that $f$ in the weal $L^p$ space?

Comment: I have impression that $\int\limits_0^\infty t^{p-1}\lambda_f(t)\,dt<\infty$ is equivalent to $f\in L^p.$